# Как создать калькулятор услуг на JS или jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как на JS или jQuery, создать такой калькулятор?

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="type-direction">Направление</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="type-direction">
            <option value="0">Выберите направление</option>
            <option value="1">Йогалатес</option>
            <option value="2">Индийские танцы</option>
            <option value="2">Кундалини</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="number-sessions">Количество занятий:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="number-sessions">
            <option value="0">Выберите кол-во занятий</option>
            <option value="1">A1</option>
            <option value="2">A4</option>
            <option value="3">A6</option>
            <option value="4">A8</option>
            <option value="5">A12</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="total-price">Итоговая цена</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total-price">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Подсчитать</button>
</form>
```

--- **Если выбран:** --- 
**Йогалатес:** 
А1 - 500 руб. 
А2 - 1300 руб. 
А3 - 1700 руб. 
А4 - 2000 руб. 
А5 - 2700 руб.

--- **Если выбран:** --- 
**Индийские танцы:** 
А1 - 500 руб. 
А2 - 1500 руб. 
А3 - 2100 руб. 
А4 - 2500 руб. 
А5 - 3300 руб.

--- **Если выбран:** --- 
**Кундалини:** 
А1 - пусто 
А2 - 1400 руб. 
А3 - 1900 руб. 
А4 - 2300 руб. 
А5 - 3100 руб.

Может где-то примеры такого калькулятора встречали, подскажите пожалуйста, я пробовал сам это на JS сделать но не вышло, не хватает знаний...

Вот как это выглядит:

[image]

Comment: _реализовать это:_, _как осуществить это?_ - что это?

Comment: Исправил, простите, спешу, паникую.

Comment: _я пробовал сам это на JS сделать_ - покажите что пытались, и что не получилось

Comment: стыдно показывать, потому что там не так как привел пример Sergiks. Главная мысль "надо брать значения обоих select'ов", а я этого не делал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По событию изменения любого из двух select'ов, надо брать значения обоих, находить соотв. цену и вставлять её в поле "total". С jQuery примерно так:

```js
var $dir = $('#type-direction')
   ,$num = $('#number-sessions')
   ,$tot = $('#total-price')
   ,prices = {
   // номер_направления: { номер_кол-ва: цена, }
     1: { 1: 500, 2: 1300, 3: 1700, 4: 2000, 5: 2700 },
     2: { 1: 500, 2: 1500, 3: 2100, 4: 2500, 5: 3300 },
     3: { 1: null,2: 1400, 3: 1900, 4: 2300, 5: 3100 }
   }
;

function update() {
  var dir = $dir.val(); // значение направления
  var num = $num.val(); // значение кол-ва
  $tot.val( prices[dir]  &&  prices[dir][num]); 
}

// слушать собятия обновления значений
$dir.on('change', update);
$num.on('change', update);
```

```html
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="type-direction">Направление</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="type-direction">
            <option value="0">Выберите направление</option>
            <option value="1">Йогалатес</option>
            <option value="2">Индийские танцы</option>
            <option value="3">Кундалини</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="number-sessions">Количество занятий:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="number-sessions">
            <option value="0">Выберите кол-во занятий</option>
            <option value="1">A1</option>
            <option value="2">A4</option>
            <option value="3">A6</option>
            <option value="4">A8</option>
            <option value="5">A12</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="total-price">Итоговая цена</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total-price">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Подсчитать</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Теперь глаза полностью раскрылись, вот что нужно было сделать "надо брать значения обоих select'ов", а я этого не знал, спасибо вам большое, низкий поклон!

Comment: Не за что )   У меня бывали такие же ступоры на, как потом уже казалось, тривиальных моментах.